# Merge a class style and inline style on input element?

Tags: html, css

I have a class style named `Number` with a width of 100px. I have a lot of input elements with this class applied; but I want one to be 140px instead. I don't want to define a new class to be applied only to one element.

Comment: Why doesn't the inline style work? It should take precedence over the class. `style='width: 140px'`

Comment: Please provide your HTML and CSS. You can see - @Foobar jsfiddle run correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this without any problems.

SEE [jsfiddle.net/DtG5X/](http://jsfiddle.net/DtG5X/)

```
<style>
    .number {
    width : 100px;

}
</style>
<input class="number" /><br />
<input class="number" /><br />
<input class="number" /><br />
<input class="number" style="width:140px;"/><br />
```

Comment: Thanks !!! (I had a mistake with ; " ...